# How to select multiple dates in TapKu library?

Tags: xcode, tapku

I would like to **show** the **multiple selected dates in tapkilibrary** .like **highlight** the **dates between 14aug2011 to 18aug2011** .

Answer (score 4):

```
    -(NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate{

NSLog(@"Date Selected is %@",date);
        //txtbdate.text=date;

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [timeFormat setTimeZone:gmt];


    //[timeFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    //[timeFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; 
    NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:date];   
    NSLog(@"%@",theTime); 
    objappdel.strdate=theTime;

    [tkmonthView reload];
    AppointmentDetail *appointmentDetail=[[AppointmentDetail alloc]initWithNibName:@"AppointmentDetail" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:appointmentDetail animated:YES];
    [appointmentDetail release];
}

- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate
{   
    NSMutableArray * data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *dateForm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateForm setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [dateForm setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSDate *date ;


    for (int i=0; i<[objappdel.arrDate count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *time;
        time=[objappdel.arrDate objectAtIndex:i];
        //time=  [[[jobData valueForKey:@"Record"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"JobStartDate"];
        //time = [[time componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        date = [dateForm dateFromString:time];
        [data addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date]];
    }
    NSArray *copy = [data copy];
        NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;
        for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) 
        {
            if ([data indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) 
            {
                [data removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            }
            index--;
        }

    NSLog(@"sorted dates are %@",copy);
    // Initialise empty marks array, this will be populated with TRUE/FALSE in order for each day a marker should be placed on.
    NSMutableArray *marks = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Initialise calendar to current type and set the timezone to never have daylight saving
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // Construct DateComponents based on startDate so the iterating date can be created.
    // Its massively important to do this assigning via the NSCalendar and NSDateComponents because of daylight saving has been removed 
    // with the timezone that was set above. If you just used "startDate" directly (ie, NSDate *date = startDate;) as the first 
    // iterating date then times would go up and down based on daylight savings.
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                              NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
                                    fromDate:startDate];
    NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

    // Init offset components to increment days in the loop by one each time
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setDay:1];    


    // for each date between start date and end date check if they exist in the data array
    while (YES) {
        // Is the date beyond the last date? If so, exit the loop.
        // NSOrderedDescending = the left value is greater than the right
        if ([d compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        {
            break;
        }

        // If the date is in the data array, add it to the marks array, else don't
        //NSLog(@"%@",[d description]);

        if ([data containsObject:[d description]]) {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        } else {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        }

        // Increment day using offset components (ie, 1 day in this instance)
        d = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:d options:0];
    }

    [offsetComponents release];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:marks];
}
```

Use this delegate method. It will return an NSArray of dates which you want to highlight.

Comment: Interesting how your rather simple and short answers all get around 10 up votes.

Comment: @Dhara what is AppointmenDetail and tkMonthView in your code? Moreover, it doesn;t return any array from the code. I am sure it doesn't work! You got the rest code from - http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers#the-code demo code. Don;t you? I am trying to do something more. If possible could you ans this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686684/ios-tapku-calendar-library-allow-selecting-multiple-dates-for-current-month Thanks.

Comment: @AppleDeveloper tkMonthView is the object of TkMonthView class. AppointmenDetail is my local class. Well i got code from gitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first entering the dates in to an array. code for this is.

```
 - (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
NSLog(@"selected Date IS - %@",inDate);

[myArray addObject:d];

for (id entry in myArray)
{

    if (inDate == nil && outDate == nil)
    {
        inDate = d;
        outDate = d;
    }
    if ([d compare:inDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        inDate = d;
    }
    if ([d compare:outDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        outDate = d;
    }

    d = nil;
}
```

}

After this you have to use a button click action by which you can make the dates selected between these two dates. Code for it is:

```
 - (IBAction)goBtn:(id)sender
  {
NSLog(@"startDate is: %@",inDate);
NSLog(@"endDate is: %@",outDate);

[calendar reload];
inDate = nil;
outDate = nil;

}
```

}

Then in one delegate method you just have to make an array containing all the dates between these two dates. It will be called just after the button click. Code for it is:

```
 - (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {
//***********
NSMutableArray *tempData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDate *nextDate;
for ( nextDate = inDate ; [nextDate compare:outDate] < 0 ; nextDate = [nextDate addTimeInterval:24*60*60] ) {
    // use date
    NSLog(@"%@",nextDate);
    [tempData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextDate]];
}
[tempData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",outDate]];
//***********


NSMutableArray *marks = [NSMutableArray array];


NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit |
                                          NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)
                                fromDate:startDate];
NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:1];


while (YES) {
    if ([d compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        break;
    }

    if ([tempData containsObject:[d description]]) {
        [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    } else {
        [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }

    d = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:d options:0];
}

return [NSArray arrayWithArray:marks];
```

}

I hope, this helped you. Please let me know if you face any problem.