# iOS: Make Tapku calendar library tiles grid size to 6x6 always

Tags: ios, calendar, tapku

I noticed that Tapku calendar grid resized between 5x5 and 6x6 depending on the month's dates distribution. For example it displays 5x5 grid for March 2012 and displays 6x6 grid for September 2012! For me it makes GUI alignments go wrong so I want grid to be always 6x6. I have been looking into TKCalenderMonthView's rangeOfDatesInMonthGrid method but not getting how it creates the grid! Could anyone please tell me how to fix the grid 6x6 always.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi if u want a dot instead of blue title then i have that code and y u want to change calendar to 6*6 u can get height if u want

Comment: Did you get the solution? I'm also trying to fix height of calendar to   6x6 always. Please help.

Comment: nope...I had to use work around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to 2nd Point.If you want to display a mark on selected and remove mark from deselected dates then use follwoing code.(It wont display blue mark)

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
NSLog(@"calendarMonthView didSelectDate");

NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

NSString *strqw=[df stringFromDate:d];
NSLog(@"%@",strqw);
NSString *stss=[strqw stringByAppendingString:@" 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSLog(@"%@",stss);
int k=0;
for (int i=0; i<[array1 count]; i++) {
    if([[array1 objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:stss]){
         [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        k=1;
    }
}
if(k==0)
[array1 addObject:stss];

[calendar reload];
}
```

And add this line
`NSArray *data=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array1];`
in the below method

```
 - (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate
```

Comment: Thanks Dhara but I already know about dot. I don't want that. I want to persist blue background until I select that date again. I want to use 6x6 grid always so that it doesn't resize between 5x5 and 6x6 and makes my GUI looks ugly.

Comment: This will just bring a dot instead of Blue Background the functionality is same its ok np. U can get the size of calendar dynamically if u want it.

Comment: Nope. I want blue background! I don't want to get the size. I want to make 6x6 grid size always!r

Comment: @AppleDeveloper what i have done is not exactly u want but once just implement this code it will help u further.U can change this dot symbol to what u want.

Comment: Hey Dhara, let's not run around the dot! I have already implemented it and I knew it before posting this question but I want to change the date selected background! Anyway if you can just tell me if I can set grid size always 6x6 then that would be great!

Comment: @AppleDeveloper the dot which u talking is differnt from what i am telling u.If u can send me ur emailID i can mail that sample code to u.If u want to make it 6*6 then what u want to display i the extra space of 5*5 calendar

Comment: Yah I am fine with that Dhara. The extra space for 5*5 should be fine! Also tell me how to get the height of the calendar please. You can send me sample on jignesh.shah80@gmail.com Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dhara, please help me to resolve 6x6 grid issu asap so that I can assign you bounty points before they expired! Thanks.

Comment: @AppleDeveloper i hope u have recieved my mail. I dont think that it will be possible to convert everything to 6*6 but u can do one thing u can find the height as how i told u and check the height and accordingly add some space when its 5*5.Bcoz even if we use 5*5 and convert it into 6*6 we need to display the next months in the same grid so i dont think so its possible

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to get the hight of current month. Can I figure it out of Month changed event?

Comment: sorry Dhara. I mentioned my email wrong by mistake. Could you please resend it to jignesh.shah1980@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for all your help on chat and mail. I would post the solution when I decide final outcome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little hack I use:

In the viewDidAppear I have

```
[calendar selectDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-31*24*60*60]];
[calendar selectDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];
```

And in the

```
- (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView monthDidChange:(NSDate*)month animated:(BOOL)animated{
```

I just check the height of my calendar and do whatever I need to do. This is done because if you check the height of the frame immediately after instantiation of the calendar, it will return the normal 5*7 height instead of the 6*7.

Hope that helps!