# iOS: Tapku Calendar: Need to select multiple dates

Tags: ios, date, calendar, tapku

I've been checking the Tapku Calendar code for a bit and searched and read all the relevant questions and responses here however none seem to really offer the correct solution to the problem: How to select multiple dates, either programmatically or by tapping. Just a simple blue tile over two adjacent dates would make me happy :-) The post below seems to have a similar question however the answer does not work. The place in the code is not hit unless the month changes - not exactly what I am looking for. What would be great is a higher-level implementation of selectDate: that would select multiple dates. But just the right place to tweak in the library would be a great place to start is anyone is more familiar with the code. Much appreciated.

[iOS: Tapku calendar library - allow selecting multiple dates for current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686684/ios-tapku-calendar-library-allow-selecting-multiple-dates-for-current-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of stepping through code, I have this rudimentary method using a hammer. I adopted most of the code from TKCalendarMonthView.m->selectDay:day method. The method I created basically creates a new TKCalendarMonthTiles object and fills in the details and then adds subviews onto the main TKCalendarMonthTiles object (self). I tag the subviews so I can first get rid of them if they exist at the beginning of the method as I only want to select one additional day (you could leave the subviews attached if you want them to remain in the UI). I don't track the dates or store them or anything however this meets my needs.

The idea is to simply create a view with the correct tile image you want to use and one that contains the text label of the actual "date" like "14" then add those views as subviews to self. The borrowed code does all the calculations for "where" that date tile resides in the grid, so the view is drawn at the correct location. Code:

```
- (void)markDay:(int)day {

// First, remove any old subviews
[[self viewWithTag:42] removeFromSuperview];
[[self viewWithTag:43] removeFromSuperview];

int pre = firstOfPrev < 0 ?  0 : lastOfPrev - firstOfPrev + 1;
int tot = day + pre;
int row = tot / 7;
int column = (tot % 7)-1;

TKCalendarMonthTiles *deliveryTile = [[TKCalendarMonthTiles alloc] init];
deliveryTile.selectedImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/MyDateTile.png")];
deliveryTile.currentDay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",day];

if(column < 0){
    column = 6;
    row--;
}

CGRect r = deliveryTile.selectedImageView.frame;
r.origin.x = (column*46);
r.origin.y = (row*44)-1;
deliveryTile.selectedImageView.frame = r;
deliveryTile.currentDay.frame = r;
[[deliveryTile selectedImageView] setTag:42];
[[deliveryTile currentDay] setTag:43];
[self addSubview:deliveryTile.selectedImageView];
[self addSubview:deliveryTile.currentDay];
} // markDay:
```

I call this method at the end of TKCalendarMonthView.m->selectDay:day as well as at the end of TKCalendarMonthView.m->-reactToTouch:down. Limited testing so far so good. Off to figure out why the timezone setting keeps thinking its tomorrow (I am in Pacific time zone).

Cheers, Michael